# ruby function that checks if one of given number is integer power of another one

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718767/check-if-array-elements-are-power-of-two) post, I wanted to generalize the problem. 
to check if given number m is integer power of number n.

[Here is](http://repl.it/j1u) my first attempt and and as I tested it, everything is ok.

Then I attempted to write something different inspired from a response to the post on the link. 
Main idea is to check if logarithm of one number on base of another is integer or not. For this reason I used natural logarithm knowing that,
log<sub>a</sub><sup>b</sup>/log<sub>a</sub><sup>c</sup> =log<sub>c</sub><sup>b</sup>

(my ruby version is 1.8.7)

```
def m_is_power_of_n(m,n)

    #false by definiton

    f1  = (n==0 and m!=0)
    f2 = (n==1 and m!=1)

    #true by definition

    t1 = m==n
    t2 = m==1

    if f1 or f2
        return false
    elsif t1 or t2
        return true
    else
        a = Math.log(m)/Math.log(n) 
        return a.to_i == a #updated after steenslag's comment
        #if a.to_i == a
        #    return true
        #else 
        #    return false
        #end
    end
end
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong because when I pass arguments (36,6), (125,5) it returns `true` as I expected. But for (216,6) or (25,5) it returns `false`.

P.S. btw, I am a ruby newbie, all criticisms about coding style are welcome :)

Comment: Note that Ruby 1.8.7+ supports an optional argument to Math.log `Math.log(36, 6) # => 2.0`

Comment: Regarding style: `a.to_i == a` returns true or false by itself, no need for an if-statement.

Comment: 216 isn't a power of 3

Comment: @FrederickCheung it is a typo, i intended to write (216, 6)

Comment: @steenslag my `ruby  -- version` returns `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]` and passing two arguments to log method raises `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Comment: Yes , with Ruby 1.8.7+ I meant Ruby > 1.8.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a precision problem, as you could see if you used `irb`

```
irb(main):001:0> Math.log(216)
=> 5.375278407684165
irb(main):002:0> Math.log(6)
=> 1.791759469228055
irb(main):003:0> Math.log(216)/Math.log(6)
=> 3.0000000000000004
```

And unfortunately 3.0000000000000004 isn't equal to 3.

You could possibly round the result...

```
a = (Math.log(m)/Math.log(n)).round(14)
```

Comment: it was one of my fears but now i just typed (ruby version 1.8.7) your 3rd expression and it spitted out 3.0. regardless of this result i think the problem is something like that.

i'll now check rounding.

Comment: round(number) is ok for ruby 2.2 (checked on repl.it), but for 1.8.7 it raises `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` . just round() without argument  is a candidate to solve shown problems but this will cause another big errors like, (61, 6) also will evaluate true.

Comment: I still prefer your original code... and of course you can implement it as an integer method... `class Integer;def is_power_of(a_number); return true if self == 1;return false if self == 0; a_number = a_number / self while a_number % self == 0; a_number == 1;end;end`   This would let you do `5.is_power_of 125`

Comment: i also do prefer it. but what is problem with logarithms? especially on my ruby version. maybe my expectation from ruby for change of base is problematic.

Comment: Well, clearly there are improvements in later versions of ruby.  If you could  upgrade to 1.9, even, you would have the ability to pass an argument to the `#round` method.  Under 1.8.7 you could approximate the round method with `a = (a * 10000000000000).to_i / 10000000000000.0 ; return a.to_i == a`